# Sorting ElasticSearch query by multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some data that I'm trying to sort in a very specific order.

I've looked over a few questions here on SO and [Elasticsearch sort on multiple queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26013557/8083803) was pretty helpful. From what I can tell I'm getting the data back in the correct order but it's not always the same data and appears to be very random as to what is returned from the query.

My question is, how do I get my data sorted correctly and get the expected data each time?

**Example Data**

```
[
    {
        id: 00,
        ...
        current_outage: {
            device_id: 00,
            ....
        },
        forecasted_outages: [
            {
                device_id: 00
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 01,
        ...
        current_outage: {
            device_id: 01,
            ....
        },
        forecasted_outages: []
    },
    {
        id: 02,
        ...
        current_outage: null,
        forecasted_outages: [
            {
                device_id: 02
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 03,
        ...
        current_outage: null,
        forecasted_outages: []
    },
]
```

**Current Query**

```js
bool: {
    should: [
        {
            constant_score: {
                boost: 6,
                filter: {
                    nested: {
                        path: 'current_outage',
                        query: {
                            exists: {
                                field: 'current_outage'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            nested: {
                path: 'forecasted_outages',
                query: {
                    exists: {
                        field: 'forecasted_outages'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Just to reiterate, the above query returns the data in the format/sorted method I expect but it does NOT return the data that I expect each time. The returned data is very random as far as I can tell.

**Sort Criteria**:

- First: Data with both `current_outage` and one or more `forecasted_outages`
- Second: Data with only `current_outage`
- Third: Data with only `forecasted_outages`

### Edit

The data returning can be anything from zero to thousands of results depending on a user. The user has an option to paginate the data or return all of their relevant data.

### Edit 2

The data returned will be anywhere from zero to 1,000 hits.

Comment: what is the total hits count?

Comment: I was just about to add this into the question but the total hits could be anything from zero to thousands of results. The data will typically be paginated which I've accounted for but did not include in the example but there is also the option to return all of a users data as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the search hits is more than 10 (default result size) and all documents have same score (in your case it could be as you are provided constant score), then the data returned could be different for each run (giving randomness feeling).

The reason for this is, the search results are merged from different shards till the hit count reaches 10 and rest of the results are ignored. So every run can have different result based on the shards merged.

Increasing the result size to include all the search result can provide same data for every run.

**UPDATE**

Changing the Shard count to 1 might help (you have close and reopen the index if the index is already created).

```
PUT /twitter/_settings
{
    "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    }
}
```

Comment: What if we were working with something smaller for now. Say users could only get a max of 30 hits paginated in sets of 10 so it would take three seperate calls to paginate through all the data. How do I make sure that page 1 will always return the same data (same goes for page 2 and 3)

Comment: updated my answer to change the number of shard to 1. since the result set here is only around 1000, this should not have any performance issues.